# How Do I Allow the User to Download a Text File Created within my Code?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, user-input

I am writing a program that takes text files from their file path and then it will iterate through the text file, turn it into a Pandas Dataframe, and then only return certain rows the meet a user-entered parameter. This all works correctly, but now I want to turn this new altered Dataframe into its own text file and allow the user to download it on their computer. Is there a Python Module that allows for this?

This is what I have written so for the function that is supposed to make the file and let them download it;

```
def SaveToANewFile():
    global dropAllNan #the var from the other function which holds the altered Dataframe

    askToSave = input("Do you want to save your created Dataframe, as it is above, as a text file to your machine? Please enter 'yes' or 'no', it is case sen.: ")

    if askToSave == str("yes"):
        filenameUser = input("What do you want to name the text file of this created Dataframe?: ")
        userFile = open(filenameUser, "w+")
        userFile.write(dropAllNan)
        userFile.close()
```

Comment: As a software design comment--globals are discouraged--it's preferred that dropAllNan is passed as an argument to SaveToANewFile.

Answer (score 0):

DataFrame.to_csv() should work for this task

```
def SaveToANewFile():
    global dropAllNan #the var from the other function which holds the altered Dataframe

    askToSave = input("Do you want to save your created Dataframe, as it is above, as a text file to your machine? Please enter 'yes' or 'no', it is case sen.: ")

    if askToSave == str("yes"):
        filenameUser = input("What do you want to name the text file of this created Dataframe?: ")
        dropAllNan.to_csv(f"{filenameUser}.txt", index=None, sep='\t')
```

Comment: Thank you, I have implemented this into my code, putting it inside the functions instead of its own function, but is there a way to have it automatically downloaded to the user's computer?